# Clear activity stack and start new Activity from service android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

My Android application consists of many activities, each of which represent a menu:

- Activity A (the main Activity & first level menu)
- Activity B (second level menu)
- Activity C (third and last menu)

I am monitoring the user's action in a service. When an event (detected by service) occurs, I want to close all of Activities and restart Activity A. The code I wrote below only works in an Activity, not a Service:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("main.activity", "ActivityA");
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

How can I do this in a Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("main.activity", "ActivityA");
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Sorry, typo. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: And if I want call onCreate for ActivityA and not onResume? What can I do?

Comment: Ah, then just remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` from the list of flags. This will cause all activities in the task to finish and it will create a new instance of `ActivityA` (thereby calling `onCreate()`).